# Installing sentry-rails 4.3.4 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sentry

I installed `sentry-rails` just fine on my machine (macOS) but when I push to Heroku I get an error:

```
       Installing sentry-rails 4.3.4
       Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       
       current directory:
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/ruby-3.0.1/bin/ruby -I
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r
       ./siteconf20210410-255-xsoxeg.rb extconf.rb
       creating Makefile
       Applying
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/disable-building-tests.patch
       Applying
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/disable-werror-on-osx.patch
       Applying
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/disable-xcode-debugging.patch
       Applying
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/do-not-imply-vfp3-and-armv7.patch
       Applying
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/do-not-use-MAP_NORESERVE-on-freebsd.patch
       Applying
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/do-not-use-vfp2.patch
       Applying
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/patches/fPIC-for-static.patch
       Compiling v8 for x64
       Using python 2.7.18
       Using compiler: c++ (GCC version 9.3.0)
       Beginning compilation. This will take some time.
       Building v8 with env CXX=c++ LINK=c++  /usr/bin/make x64.release
       ARFLAGS.target=crs werror=no
       GYP_GENERATORS=make \
       build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                     -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
                     -Dv8_target_arch=x64 \
       -S.x64  -Dv8_enable_backtrace=1
       -Dv8_can_use_vfp2_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv2
       -Dv8_can_use_vfp3_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv3 -Dwerror=''
       make[1]: Entering directory
       '/tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/vendor/v8/out'
       CXX(target)
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o
       CXX(target)
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o
       CXX(target)
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum.o
       CXX(target)
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum-dtoa.o
       CXX(target)
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o
       CXX(target)
       /tmp/build_404d6dcb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/conversions.o
       In file included from ../src/utils.h:36,
                        from ../src/conversions.h:31,
                        from ../src/conversions-inl.h:40,
                        from ../src/conversions.cc:32:
       ../src/scanner.h: In member function ‘void v8::internal::Scanner::Init()’:
```

Couldn't find anything, I'm using ruby 3.0.1

Comment: Also posted as GitHub issue: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-ruby/issues/1392

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `therubyracer` gem and it now it works fine